# Two way constraint distribution optimization in R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm, simplex

Have to solve a distribution optimization problem in R but can't seem to bring my head around the approach for formulating it effably:

**A** is a matrix of accounts and account holders with the relevant amounts available to each coordinate. The entire matrix is a network with n:m relations between accounts and account holders. I need to optimize the distribution of amounts under the following two constraints:

- **C1** => all account holders have to be covered by at least 100k 
       (or at least the max amount possible) / this condition has priority
- **C2** => maximize the amount on accounts that can be fully covered (i.e. it's better to cover only one account to 100% instead of
  multiple accounts if the total sum is higher on the single account)

We don't have any negative values involved.

I have tried to approach the problem using **OptimSimplex** and **GA** but stumbled about getting the two constraints to work on the same distribution yet including a priority for the first.

Comment: C2 sounds like an objective function, not a constraint.  What is your objective function?

Comment: also, what's with the genetic-algorithm tag, this looks like an integer linear program?

Comment: Hi Manilo, thought to solve it using GA - an you're right - C2 is really the objective function but it can only be achieved once the constraint of C1 is fulfilled. But how you fulfill C1 impacts in turn how & what you can optimize.